# How to update existing Azure SQL database table as data changes in data source table (OData link/api) and running everything in cloud?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, odata, opendata

I am working on my school project, I am stuck somewhere pls provide some help.
I have imported a table from an open data website into my Azure SQL database but the data changes every 30 minutes in the source. I wanted to update the recent data automatically every 30 minutes in the cloud.

Is that possible in `Azure SQL database`?

At this moment, I can do it through `integration services` package running manually. But I could not deploy it in Azure sql database and execute automatically.
Pls provide help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to implement that using Azure WebJob with the scheduling. You can find the tutorial [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduled). WebJob is some kind of a background service that can be executed on a schedule. Put your logic in that WebJob (get the data => put into Azure SQL) and schedule every 30 minutes.